# Hartl Rails Tutorial: Flash rendering message and hash

Tags: railstutorial.org

This is from Railstutorial.org, starting in chapter 7.
I've been banging my head on this one, so if its a simple typo I apologize.

I'm trying to get just the flash message to render, but for some reason I'm seeing the flash and also the hash that produces it showing up on my page.  Here's my code (relevant code is lines 12-15).

```html
  1 <!DOCTYPE html>$                                                                                                                                                 
  2 <html>$                                                                                                                                                          
  3     <head>$                                                                                                                                                      
  4       <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>$                                                                                                           
  5       <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>$                                                                
  6       <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>$                                                                              
  7       <%= csrf_meta_tags %>$                                                                                                                                     
  8       <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>$                                                                                                                              
  9     </head>$                                                                                                                                                     
 10     <body>$                                                                                                                                                      
 11         <%= render 'layouts/header' %>$                                                                                                                          
 12         <div class="container">$                                                                                                                                 
 13         <%= flash.each do |message_type, message| %>$                                                                                                            
 14           <%= content_tag(:div, message,  class: "alert alert-#{message_type}") %> $                                                                             
 15         <% end %>$                                                                                                                                               
 16           <%= yield %>$                                                                                                                                          
 17           <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>$                                                                                                                        
 18           <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>$                                                                                                        
 19         </div>$                                                                                                                                                  
 20     </body>$                                                                                                                                                     
 21 </html>$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out... `<%= flash.each do |message_type, message| %>` is rendering visibly. Took out the '=' above and it fixed things.